# How to restore a git reset --hard HEAD@{1}

Tags: git, git-reset, git-fsck

I do a

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

But I removed some things wrongly. I try solve it

```
git fsck −−lost-found
```

But it no found the "revert"

Thanks...

Comment: git reflog. Find the commit you reverted and reapply it.

Comment: `git revert` doesn't have a `--hard`: do you mean `git reset`?  Either way, search, as both questions have been answered.

Comment: When you `reset --hard` you throw away three things.  Commits, the index, and the working directory.  Working directory is gone forever, index is difficult to recover, commits are trivial.  Edit your question with additional information about what you are trying to recover.

Comment: Yes, I do a commit with the wrong changes, and after I also made a wrong reset. With git reflog @gran_profaci I find the reset and reapply it... Thanks